# Python - Import file into multiple arrays, dicts, tuples

Tags: python, arrays, loops, iteration, tuples

How do you create a new array/tuple every new line?
Like I have this loop to read the file:

```
for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\t\t', doublequote=False, skipinitialspace=True):
    orar = OraRend._make(line[1:])
```

How can I create a tuple for every line?
(Since now, it'll run line by line, and I'll have the latest line as my "orar", which is not what I want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orar = []    
for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', lineterminator='\t\t', doublequote=False, skipinitialspace=True):
    orar.append(OraRend._make(line[1:]))
```

Comment: @Shiki: we all feel that urge from time to time ;)